# Define Assumption/Theorem... "numbering text" in Lyx

Tags: lyx

Is there any way to redefine Assumption numbering in Lyx? For example, in the following example, the Assumption numbering is "2*". Can I do this just for once instead of redefining it globally over the entire documents?

[image]
When cited, it looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What document class are you using? Is the `*` just appended with the number still incremented? That is, you go from Assumption 1 to 2* to 3, say?

Comment: @Werner I'm using "Article (Standard Class)" with modules "Theorems (AMS, Numbered by Type)". No, Assumptions still go from 1 to 2 to 3. However, Assumption 2 has a more general version, say, Assumption 2*. Of course, I can call it Assumption 4, but Assumption 2* is a better name as it emphasis its relation with Assumption 2.

Comment: The default article class with the AMS theorems module doesn't offer an `Assumption` layout... but I guess that doesn't really matter. You may have redefined an `Example` layout to now read `Assumption`.